# Angular + PrimeNG Sub menu

Tags: html, angular, primeng, submenu

I need the submenu to consist of a dynamic array.

[image: screenshot]

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.model = [
      {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'pi pi-home',
        routerLink: ['/pages']
      },
      {separator: true},
      {
        label: 'Inventory',
        icon: 'pi pi-mobile',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'Device Inventory',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'By manufacturer',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left',
                routerLink: ['/device']
              },
              {
                label: 'By Type',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left',
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },

      {separator: true},
      {
        label: 'Potential Attack Scenarios',
        icon: 'pi pi-share-alt',
        routerLink: ['/alert']
      },
      {
        label: 'Compliance',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-download',
        routerLink: ['/alert']
      },
      {
        label: 'Alerts',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-download',
        routerLink: ['/alert']
      },
      {
        label: 'Settings',
        icon: 'pi pi-cog',
        routerLink: ['/alert']
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

But I have an array of type string. I want to put this dynamic array here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.